# mtpro2 and unicode-math

Tags: unicode-math, mtpro

I am new to Stack Exchange, so please excuse the few mistakes that might have happened.

I like the large square roots, parantheses and braces, the wide accents, underbraces, etc that one gets with `mtpro2`. Also, the TeX Gyre Pagella Math font is very much to my liking, especially since it has optical sizes inbuilt.

However, this question is not about my likings, but the fact, that I would like to use TeX Gyre Pagella Math with `unicode-math` and take (especially) the square root, braces and parantheses from `mtpro2`. Does anybody have an idea?

*Here is an MWE:* (note how the `sqrt` is not slanted and the parantheses are not round)

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont[ExternalLocation,Numbers={OldStyle,Proportional},Mapping=tex-text, ItalicFont={texgyrepagella-italic}, BoldFont = {texgyrepagella-bold}, BoldItalicFont = {texgyrepagella-bolditalic}]{texgyrepagella-regular}

\setsansfont[Scale=MatchLowercase,Numbers={OldStyle,Proportional}, Mapping=tex-text]{Calibri}
\setmathfont[ExternalLocation]{texgyrepagella-math}


\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
s_x = \sqrt{\frac{1}{n-1} \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(x_i-\overline{x}\right)^2} = \left(\sqrt[4]{\frac{\frac{1}{n-1} \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(x_i-\overline{x}\right)^2}{\left(\frac{1}{1}\right)}}\right)^2
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Good question, but not a task I'd engage in. Maybe I'll try some experiment.

Comment: What happens if you load `mtpro2` after executing `\setmathfont`?

Comment: It seems that `mtpro2` does not do any job in this case. It is overwritten by the lines that follow.